# creating wordpress theme from html pages

Tags: html, wordpress, dreamweaver

I created an HTML website in dreamweaver it has a index page, nav-menu and around 10 other linked pages. I did not build the website from templates I just copied and pasted.

I want to upload this website using Wordpress and Ive never done it before. I'm still learning but need help figuring thing out; 
I saw that in order to upload the page to Wordpress I need to create a so called theme and in order to do that I need to create different files like index.php, header.php, footer.php etc
My question is do I have to do that process with all my pages?

I mean about.html contact.html jobs.html?

What is the ideal way to do it?

Comment: You can convert an html website to a wordpress theme quickly and easily with http://wpsiteconvertor.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A WordPress template is essentially a set of PHP pages and CSS that defines how your WordPress site looks. [Template Development Link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development)

Manually converting your site is going to take time.  The advantage of the WordPress site will be that your  site will be easier to update down the line.

---

How difficult building your template and pages is really going to depend on how clean your original css and pages are built.

***First***, build your template.  You are going to try and pull your CSS and apply it to the template pages.

***Next***, you will need to use the WordPress GUI interface to add pages and include the content from your original site.

Again it is going to come down to how much of your formatting was done inline and how much you leveraged CSS in your presentation.  A lot of table formatting for example will be more difficult to translate.

Comment: Thank you mike! just so I can be clear on one thing. I create a Wordpress theme/template based on lets say my index.html then I use Wordpress GUI interface to add pages from that template like about us or contact us and then include the content on them from my original html pages?

Comment: @AbdoEl-Madhoun That's correct, template off of one page, then add the rest using wordpress.